# How do I replace a class for a child element?

Tags: javascript, html, class

I have a piece of code that, while it works perfectly elsewhere, is not working when I try to apply it to a child element. I am trying to simply replace a class in the `classList` for an `i` element when the `addEventListener("mouseover"` for the parent tag is triggered. Here's my code:

```
    document.getElementById("parentTag").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("parentTag").getElementsByTagName("i")[0];
        
        elem.classList.replace = ("fal", "fas");
    });
```

This should be pretty straight forward but, for some reason that I cannot determine, it is not working here. I can do other things with this element (e.g. change `style` attributes, etc.) but anything involving `classList` (`replace`, `add`, `remove`) is completely failing. I can however call the `classList` into the console with `console.log(elem.classList.value);` but I can't change it.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what I might be doing wrong?

*NOTE: Sorry if the question was a little unclear, I don't know how to better describe it outright. If you need clarification please let me know.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You accidentally used an assignment operator for `classList.replace()`. It should be `elem.classList.replace("fal", "fas")`.

```js
document.getElementById("parentTag").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
     var elem = document.getElementById("parentTag").getElementsByTagName("i")[0];
     elem.classList.replace("fal", "fas");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this was it. It's been a long day lol...